# I cant connect Database on plesk Dotnet Core Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework-core, plesk

I publish the app with the Visual studio web deploy method and an edit appsettings.json but I can't connect the database. I can't find a true connection string anywhere or method.

I tried phpmyAdmin connection string and host Ip on the connection string, add webconfig to connection string and some possibilities on connection string but it doesn't work

```
app settings.json
 {"ConnectionStrings": {
      "add": "name=DatabaseContext"
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=schoolDatabase;Integrated Security=False;User ID=adminAdmin;Password=********;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096"
  }
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false" allowOverride="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\webapplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>

      <trust level="Full" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

> Error message is:  Http 500 and  HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure.

I can't get any log

Answer (score 1):

Connection string should not be `.\MSSQLSERVER2012` on Pleasek (production). From pleask where you create a SQL server DB - there find the connection string. It is usually an IP based. e.g. `Data Source=10.10.10.10\SQLEXPRESS`